# A problem with polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, problem-solving

This is a problem from a test in my course in analytic functions. I didn't manage to solve it. Could you please give me a hint? The problem is:

Calculate the third root of the sum of the coefficients of the polynomial whose roots are the squares of the roots of the following polynomial:

$$P(z)=z^5-z+11.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this for a polynomial of degree $2$, with omission of some steps that you will probably be able to fill in yourself:
$$ P(z) = (z-a)(z-b), $$
then the polynomial under investigation is
$$ Q(z) = (z-a^2)(z-b^2) $$
The sum of its coefficients is $Q(1)$:
$$ Q(1) = (1-a)(1+a)(1-b)(1+b) = P(1)P(-1) $$

So the answer would be
$$ \sqrt[3]{ P(1)P(-1)},$$

I'll leave the details and generalisation to other degrees to you. (Note that there is an extra $-1$ appearing for odd degrees!)

Comment: Eh. Difference of squares. I'm a fourth-year student in mathematics. Thank you!